# RAML - modeling dependencies between query prams

Tags: raml

I am modelling an API with RAML and I am wondering if it’s possible to model dependencies between a query parameters.

Let’s say we’ve got a collection of objects. A user can narrow the query results down by specifying an object type and a state. Here’s a bit of RAML that should do what I just said:

```
/objects:
  - searchable:
    queryParameters: 
        object-type:
            enum: [Type1, Type2, Type3]
        object-state:
            enum: [State1, State2, State3]
```

Now above definition may make the users feel that it's possible to use any combination they want - what is not quite right, as: 
- object of 'Type1' can take just 'State1', 
- object of 'Type2' can take 'State2' and 'State3', 
- object of 'Type3' can take 'State1', 'State2', 'State3'.

Does anyone know how to model that with RAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible in RAML. RAML is intended to describe an API, and that is more oriented to be business logic.

Nevertheless, I've heard about this question from a lot of people, and I think that it could be treated in [RAML 1.0](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/milestones/v1.0)

Cheers!

Comment: I see, but I've got another problem.

Comment: Lets say we've got POST method with 3 arguments.

I'd like a user to supply either (param_1) or (param_2 and param_3), as ie: param_2 alone doesn't contain enough info to complete the request.

How can I model that?